# "Find the number" puzzle

Tags: performance, c

A friend gave this puzzle:

Find 3 numbers (say, A B C) such that

> \$ABC+ABC+ABC = CCC\$

ABC means \$((A*100) + (B*10) + C)\$. Also, these 3 digits must be distinct.

I wrote a quick code to find out the answer:

```
int main(void) {
    // your code goes here
    int hun,dec,unit;
    int final_num = 0;
    int temp_num = 0;
    for(hun = 0; hun <10; hun++)
    {
        for(dec = 0; dec < 10; dec++)
        {
            for(unit = 0; unit < 10; unit++)
            {
                // Calculate the number which would be formed with this unit place
                final_num = (unit *100) + (unit * 10) + (unit);

                // Values should not be same
                if((unit!=dec) && (unit != hun) &&( dec != hun))
                {
                    // Number with current combo of ABC
                    temp_num = ((hun * 100) + (dec * 10) + unit) * 3;
                    if(temp_num ==final_num )
                    {
                        printf("Number is %d \n",temp_num);
                        printf(" Hun %d Dec %d Unit %d",hun,dec,unit);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    printf("\nEnd of File ");
    return 0;
}
```

And the Answer was 185 (185 + 185 + 185 = 555).

That was very amateur code. Upon thinking, I realized I could have implemented equation \$300A + 30B + 3C = 111C\$. But still couldn't avoid `for` loop.
What could be the better way to implement this? I know only C so I solved it with C.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm sorry, but the best solution to this problem has to be a logic solution, not a code solution. There are only 2 digits that, when multiplied by 3, have the same last digit... 0, and 5. So, 0+0+0 is 0, and 5+5+5 is 15.

Since C cannot be 0, it means that C can only be 5. Now, if C is 5, and we know that there is a 'carry' of 1 in to the tens column, it means we need to find a number other than 5 that when added together 3 times ends in a 4.

There is only one value that does that, 8. 8 + 8 + 8 is 24, and with the carry of 1, we have 25 (and a carry of 2 in to the 100's column).

So, now we need a digit that sums three times to 3, and that's 1.

There is only one possible solution where ABC + ABC + ABC is CCC, and that's 185. It can be deduced using logic alone, and brute-forcing it is overkill.

Comment: In other words, anything better then brute force requires logically analyzing the algorithm you'd use, which should naturally lead to solving the problem without a single line of code!

Comment: Although, technically, since you've outlined thus answer, someone could conceptually write a program that figures this out programmatically without knowing the solution, by solving for one digit at a time from left to right, with a possible backtracking algorithm in case of partial matches.

Answer (score 4):

The most stringent condition in the requirements is that the sum will have 3 digits that are all the same. Maybe it's easier to work from this angle. So, you can just use one loop from 1 to 9, form the number, divide by 3, and check the other conditions.

```
for (int c = 1; c <= 9; ++c) {
    int ccc = 111 * c;
    int abc = ccc / 3;
    int ab = abc / 10;
    int a = ab / 10;
    int b = ab % 10;
    int abc_c = abc % 10;
    if (c == abc_c && a != b && b != c && a != c) {
        printf("%d * 3 = %d\n", abc, abc * 3);
    }
}
```

Comment: It's probably worth pointing out that we know the division `ccc / 3` will always be exact (because 111 is 3*37 - in fact, that means we could write `abc = c * 37)`).  If that were not the case, we'd need an additional test.

Answer (score 0):

I'll ignore the fact that the puzzle can be solved logically, without brute-force search, and concentrate on the code itself.

We're missing an include of `<stdio.h>` to declare `printf()`.

The comment `// your code goes here` is unnecessary.

Prefer to define variables with the minimum reasonable scope, and initialise as they are declared.  For example,

```
for (int hun = 0;  hun < 10;  ++hun)
```

The test for unequal digits is inefficient in the inner loop.  We could skip entire outer loops:

```
    for (int dec = 0;  dec < 10;  ++dec) {
        if (dec == hun) {
            continue;
        }
        for (int unit = 0;  unit < 10;  ++unit) {
            if (unit == dec || unit == hun) {
                continue;
            }
```

`temp_num` is a poor name for a variable.  The scope and type can show us it's a temporary number, but what the reader needs to know is what it *means*.  I'd name it using the notation of the problem domain, `abc`.  And I'd write `ccc` rather than `final_num`.

Prefer to print complete lines (ending in newline), rather than partial (unterminated) lines:

```
      printf(" Hun %d Dec %d Unit %d\n", hun, dec, unit);
```

There's no need for the "End of file" message - successful exit is enough to indicate the end of output.  And (unlike normal functions) `main()` can implicitly return success without writing `return 0;`.

Applying these improvements, we end up with this brute-force program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    for (int a = 0;  a < 10;  ++a) {
        for (int b = 0;  b < 10;  ++b) {
            if (b == a) {
                /* digits must be distinct */
                continue;
            }
            for (int c = 0;  c < 10;  ++c) {
                if (c == b || c == a) {
                    /* digits must be distinct */
                    continue;
                }
                int abc = a * 100 + b * 10 + c;
                int ccc = c * 100 + c * 10 + c;
                if (abc + abc + abc == ccc) {
                    printf("%d + %d + %d = %d\n", abc, abc, abc, ccc);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```